How to combine two Maybes
I'm curious of different ways of combining Maybes. There's a small example of what I am able to achieve with a do (I reckon using the fact Maybe is a monad), however for this particular example I'm wondering if I can just use the semigroup. I tried something like
instance Semigroup (Maybe Int) where
  (Just x) <> (Just y) = Just (x + y)
  _ <> _ = Nothing

but this just throws a compile error. Parametrising over Num a would be the next step. My thought was if it was possible to just combine like m1 <> m2 as writing extra functions feels unnecessary, though I don't have a good grasp of things yet.
Example of what I'm trying to do:
m1 :: Maybe Int
m1 = Just 1

m2 :: Maybe Int
m2 = Just 11

m3 :: Maybe Int
m3 = Nothing

combine :: (Num a) => Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
combine x y = do
  a <- x
  b <- y
  return (a + b)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ combine m1 m2
  print $ combine m1 m3
  print $ combine m2 m3

Results:
Just 12
Nothing
Nothing


There is a predefined Semigroup instance for Semigroup a => Maybe a, which just lifts <>: Just (Sum 3) <> Just (Sum 5) == Just (Sum 8), for instance. (The result is Nothing only when both operands themselves are Nothing.)

You can also use liftA2 (+).

Note that liftA2 (+) (Just 3) Nothing would be Nothing, not Just 3 (which matches the definition attempted in the question), so there are two pre-existing options to choose from depending on how you want to handle Nothing.

@chepner: based on the instance of Semigroup (Maybe Int)it needs to returnNothingif one of the two isNothing`.

The two behaviors described in the preceding comments both have Semigroup instances. One is Maybe (Sum Int), the other is Ap Maybe (Sum Int).

Mathematically, Maybe m is the free monoid on m qua semigroup, while Ap Maybe m is the free absorption monoid on m qua monoid.

Thanks for the comments everyone, this is very informative for learning Haskell. liftA2 (+) does the job precisely. How about instead of having a semigroup I wanted it to be a monoid, and have eg. Just 1 <> Nothing = Just 1, basically instead of nothing to have the mempty ?

Then use Maybe (Sum Int) or define your own instance mimicking the Semigroup (Maybe a) one.

Yes, Maybe (Sum Int) seems to do the job quite well. Now I looked at the problem I'm having with defining my own Semigroup instance, and that is overlapping instances: instance Semigroup a => Semigroup (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’, and putting something like import GHC.Base () at the top of imports doesn't seem to change the error message. Any idea how to disable this import? Sorry to bug with such basic stuff, but hopefully these answers will come in handy to others.

@toni057 You cannot prevent the import of instances, so the only choice you have would be to avoid importing GHC.Base or anything that imports it anywhere in its dependency chain. This almost certainly means you're going to need the NoImplicitPrelude pragma, and practically speaking also means you likely aren't going to be able to write any programs. I haven't checked carefully, but I'd be surprised if the module that defines IO doesn't depend on enough stuff to bring the relevant Semigroup instance into scope already.

@DanielWagner thanks for clarifying. So how does one go about redefining existing instances? What is the approach?

That's not the only choice: you can use overlapping instances.

Thanks, I'll have a look at those.

@toni057 The standard practice if you need a difference instance than an existing one is to make a newtype. (And in this case, the relevant newtype already exists, as I explained above.) I strongly recommend avoiding overlapping instances; it is relatively easy to create extremely subtle bugs by getting the "wrong" instance. I programmed Haskell professionally for more than ten years without them; avoiding them is not a big cost.

Thanks @DanielWagner , I'll take your advice on this one. Cheers!


My thought was if it was possible to just combine like m1 <> m2.

It is possible. Likely the error you get is that you are defining an instance for something for which there is already a (more generic) instance. Indeed, it is defined as:
instance Semigroup a => Semigroup (Maybe a) where
  Just x <> Just y = Just (x <> y)
  Nothing <> x = x
  x <> _ = x
So if the item the Maybe is wrapping, is an instance of Semigroup, you can combine these.
Now, Int is not an instance of Semigroup, but they defined types like Sum [Hackage] and Product [Hackage] to pick the Semigroup you want, so we can work with:
Just (Sum 1) <> Just (Sum 2)  -- Just (Sum 3)

we thus can then use getSum to get the sum out of it:
getSum <$> (Just (Sum 1) <> Just (Sum 2))  -- Just 3

If one of the two is a Nothing, the other parameter is returned. This thus means that Just (Sum 1) <> Nothing is Just (Sum 1).
But probably here a more useful algebraic structure for this use case is the Applicative [Hackage]. For a Maybe, this will then combine two Justs, so:
import Control.Applicative(liftA2)

liftA2 (+) (Just 1) (Just 2)  -- Just 3


The semigroup instance doesn't seem to work, though liftA2 seems to be the thing I wanted to do - I'm quite happy to have learned about as it looks like a concept I might want to use more often.

@toni057: did you import Data.Monoid?

@willeM_VanOnsem I seem to be stumbling into duplicate declaration instance Semigroup a => Semigroup (Maybe a)  -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’ here as well.

@toni057: but you don't need to write the instance yourself, it is what the base library already has.

if you want a semigroup instance that works the way you want (more like liftA2), you can use the type Ap (Maybe (Sum Int)). Because Ap and Sum are newtypes, you should be able to use coerce to convert between Maybe Int and Ap (Maybe (Sum Int))

@Joe Ap Maybe (Sum Int), not Ap (Maybe (Sum Int)).
